# Aplicativo de chamada (telefônica) para android

Tags: android

Fiz umas pesquisas e ao que me parece não é possível criar um `app` de chamada telefônica, alguém já teve este mesmo problema, ele vai ser usado como controle usando o teclado numérico, o `app` padrão funciona, mas o cliente quer que fique mais amigável visualmente trocando os números por ícones!

Comment: Não deu pra entender a sua dúvida, o que você está tentando fazer?

Comment: Como assim um aplicativo de chamada? Você quer dizer que ligue? Ou que acesse o CallLog? Especifique melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Skype e Viber fazem chamadas.

Comment: Não lhe interessaria simplismente chamar a app de chamada telefonica do S.O.?

Comment: não porque na verdade vai ser usando como controle não pra fazer chamada por voz

Comment: e agora está mais claro minha duvida?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi. Você quer substituir o keypad padrão por um com ícones?

Comment: exatamente! @OnoSendai

Answer (score 1):

Chamada telefônica? A pergunta não ficou muito clara.

Se for isso, ai vai:
Eu nunca fiz tal implementação, mas acredito que seja possível sim. O S.O. Android é construído no mesmo framework em que desenvolvemos os aplicativos. É possível interceptar praticamente todas as ações do sistema operacional, e também é possível chamar quase todas as suas ações.

Isso deve funcionar:

```
 String uri = "tel:" + "555133333333"; // aqui, óbvio, o número para o qual deseja ligar.
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

E é preciso autorizar o uso do CALL_PHONE no arquivo manifest do aplicativo.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: lançar um intent não resolve meu problema.

Comment: Não resolve porque?
Não fez a ligação?
Estás testando em um emulador, celular ou tablet?